# How to echo all the rows of same id together from phpmyadmin in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

My code:

```
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, images.image_url
    FROM tmdb_movies
    JOIN images ON images.images_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
    GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,images.image_url");

 // Then fire it up
 $stmt->execute();
 // Pick up the result as an array
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Now you run through this array in many ways, for example
 for($x=0, $n=count($result); $x < $n; $x++){

     echo'
  '.$result[$x]["movie_title"].' - <img src="'.$result[$x]["image_url"].'"/>
  ';

}
```

Example: How this code ECHO data

```
// SOME Stuff Here
The Dark Knight: - <img src="sdfsdfds.jpg"/>
// MORE STUFF HERE
// SOME Stuff Here
The Dark Knight: - <img src="zxfdy.jpg"/>
// MORE STUFF HERE

// SOME Stuff Here
Logan - <img src="rhfrg.jpg"/>
// MORE STUFF HERE
// SOME Stuff Here
Logan - <img src="sdfsqw.jpg"/>
// MORE STUFF HERE
```

How I Want It to echo data

```
// Some Stuff Here
The Dark Knight -   <img src="sdfsdfds.jpg"/> <img src="zxfdy.jpg"/>
// More Stuff Here

 // SOME Stuff Here
Logan - <img src="rhfrg.jpg"/> <img src="sdfsqw.jpg"/>
// MORE STUFF HERE
```

I hope you understand.

Why it ECHO Data like this?

Because i am using one to many relationship table. My images table is like this:

```
tmdb_id        images
1             sfdsfds.jpg
1             zcxz.jpg
2             fsfsdfs.jpg
3             dsfsdfs.jpg
3             dsfsfs.jpg
3            dfdsfdsw.jpg
```

Both tmdb_movies and images table are connected via tmdb_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate way to display movies with one or more images. This groups by title and uses GROUP_CONCAT to create a list of images for each title.

```
$qstr = "";
$qstr .= "SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, GROUP_CONCAT(images.image_url) as `images`\n";
$qstr .= "FROM tmdb_movies\n";
$qstr .= "  JOIN images ON images.images_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id\n";
$qstr .= "GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title\n";
$qstr .= "LIMIT 10;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($qstr);

// Then fire it up
$stmt->execute();
// Pick up the result as an array
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Now you run through the results, one row per movie title.
foreach($result as $x => $row) {
    echo "\n".$row["movie_title"] . " - ";
    //  Images will be comma separated if multiple images.
    $img_list = explode(',',$row['images'];
    foreach($img_list as $c => $img) {
        echo " <img src='".$img."'/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot `DISTINCT` in group_concat. After adding it, it works perfectly :D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do a break sort, looking for duplicate movie titles, emitting the title only when it changes.

```
$qstr = "";
$qstr .= "SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, images.image_url\n";
$qstr .= "  FROM tmdb_movies\n";
$qstr .= "  JOIN images ON images.images_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id\n";
$qstr .= "  GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,images.image_url";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($qstr);

// Then fire it up
$stmt->execute();
// Pick up the result as an array
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Now you run through this array in many ways, for example
$lastTitle = "";
foreach($result as $x => $row) {
    if($lastTitle != $row["movie_title"]) {
        echo "\n".$row["movie_title"] . " - ";
        $lastTitle = $row["movie_title"];
    } else {
    }
    echo " <img src='".$row["image_url"]."'/>";
}
```

Comment: This will only work, if i want to fetch only 1 row. It will not work on my code bro

Comment: Not true. It should run through all of the rows in ```$result```. I use it all the time. Give it a try first before you make a statement like that.

Comment: Bro, I have other stuff also. I need to do the same with all things? Like, i have movie budget, movie revenue, movie...I do this with all things??

Comment: Yes, If you want to selectively display some parts of the data.

Comment: What you mean??

Comment: Thanks it works, but it messed up by pagination system.  `LIMIT 10` 

I want to limit 10 movie titile. But now, it also count 1 image_url as a row...So, if their are 3 movie title, and 7 image url. then it do not echo  more records

Comment: Of course it does. You will have to limit the number of movies in the php code. As an alternative, you could group by the movie title, and use group_concat on the image filenames, then split the images in your php code.

Comment: Can their be 2 separator in group_concat? Like this: One before and one after. 

Then i can do something like this: 

1st separtor: `<img src="` 2nd seprator at the end `" />

So the url will be like this: `<img src="sdfsf.jpg"/>`

Comment: Is this is what you mean? @sloan Or something else? Can you explain, what you mean by last comment **please**